# Remove namespace from SOAP message

Tags: c#, xml, soap

I have a question..

This is an XML document that I have to pass to some method.

```
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP:Header/>
<SOAP:Body>
<BATMAS03>
<IDOC BEGIN="1">
<EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
<TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
<MANDT>310</MANDT>
<DOCNUM>0000000000006284</DOCNUM>
<DOCREL>740</DOCREL>
<STATUS>30</STATUS>
<DIRECT>1</DIRECT>
<OUTMOD>2</OUTMOD>
<IDOCTYP>BATMAS03</IDOCTYP>
<MESTYP>BATMAS</MESTYP>
<STDMES>BATMAS</STDMES>
<SNDPOR>SAPDVJ</SNDPOR>
<SNDPRT>LS</SNDPRT>
<SNDPRN>DVJCLNT310</SNDPRN>
<RCVPOR>XML</RCVPOR>
<RCVPRT>LS</RCVPRT>
<RCVPRN>DXTCLNT330</RCVPRN>
<CREDAT>20150902</CREDAT>
<CRETIM>193043</CRETIM>
</EDI_DC40>
<E1BATMAS SEGMENT="1">
<MATERIAL>000000000000501104</MATERIAL>
<BATCH>150715L01</BATCH>
<E1BPBATCHCTRL SEGMENT="1">
<DOCLASSIFY>X</DOCLASSIFY>
</E1BPBATCHCTRL>
<E1BP3060_ALLOCATION SEGMENT="1">
<CLASS_TYPE>023</CLASS_TYPE>
<OBJECTKEY>000000000000501104150715L01</OBJECTKEY>
<OBJECTTABLE>MCH1</OBJECTTABLE>
<CLOBJECTKEY>Z_PROIZVOD</CLOBJECTKEY>
<CLASSNUM>Z_PROIZVOD</CLASSNUM>
<CLASSTYPE>023</CLASSTYPE>
</E1BP3060_ALLOCATION>
<E1BP3060_VALUATION_CHAR SEGMENT="1">
<CLASS_TYPE>023</CLASS_TYPE>
<OBJECTKEY>000000000000501104150715L01</OBJECTKEY>
<OBJECTTABLE>MCH1</OBJECTTABLE>
<CLOBJECTKEY>Z_PROIZVOD</CLOBJECTKEY>
<CHARACT>Z_EDICIJA</CHARACT>
<VALUE_CHAR>V001</VALUE_CHAR>
</E1BP3060_VALUATION_CHAR>
</E1BATMAS>
</IDOC>
</BATMAS03>
</SOAP:Body>
</SOAP:Envelope>
```

First I convert it to string like this

```
 StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
 XmlTextWriter xw = new XmlTextWriter(sw);
 XmlDoc.WriteTo(xw);
 string str = sw.ToString();
```

And then i pass that string to a method.The problem is that I want to remove or pass that string without a SOAP decleration, without this;

```
<SOAP:Envelope xmlns:SOAP="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<SOAP:Header/>
<SOAP:Body>
```

This is what I want to pass as string:

```
<BATMAS03>
<IDOC BEGIN="1">
<EDI_DC40 SEGMENT="1">
<TABNAM>EDI_DC40</TABNAM>
<MANDT>310</MANDT>
<DOCNUM>0000000000006284</DOCNUM>
<DOCREL>740</DOCREL>
<STATUS>30</STATUS>
<DIRECT>1</DIRECT>
<OUTMOD>2</OUTMOD>
<IDOCTYP>BATMAS03</IDOCTYP>
<MESTYP>BATMAS</MESTYP>
<STDMES>BATMAS</STDMES>
<SNDPOR>SAPDVJ</SNDPOR>
<SNDPRT>LS</SNDPRT>
<SNDPRN>DVJCLNT310</SNDPRN>
<RCVPOR>XML</RCVPOR>
<RCVPRT>LS</RCVPRT>
<RCVPRN>DXTCLNT330</RCVPRN>
<CREDAT>20150902</CREDAT>
<CRETIM>193043</CRETIM>
</EDI_DC40>
<E1BATMAS SEGMENT="1">
<MATERIAL>000000000000501104</MATERIAL>
<BATCH>150715L01</BATCH>
<E1BPBATCHCTRL SEGMENT="1">
<DOCLASSIFY>X</DOCLASSIFY>
</E1BPBATCHCTRL>
<E1BP3060_ALLOCATION SEGMENT="1">
<CLASS_TYPE>023</CLASS_TYPE>
<OBJECTKEY>000000000000501104150715L01</OBJECTKEY>
<OBJECTTABLE>MCH1</OBJECTTABLE>
<CLOBJECTKEY>Z_PROIZVOD</CLOBJECTKEY>
<CLASSNUM>Z_PROIZVOD</CLASSNUM>
<CLASSTYPE>023</CLASSTYPE>
</E1BP3060_ALLOCATION>
<E1BP3060_VALUATION_CHAR SEGMENT="1">
<CLASS_TYPE>023</CLASS_TYPE>
<OBJECTKEY>000000000000501104150715L01</OBJECTKEY>
<OBJECTTABLE>MCH1</OBJECTTABLE>
<CLOBJECTKEY>Z_PROIZVOD</CLOBJECTKEY>
<CHARACT>Z_EDICIJA</CHARACT>
<VALUE_CHAR>V001</VALUE_CHAR>
</E1BP3060_VALUATION_CHAR>
</E1BATMAS>
</IDOC>
</BATMAS03>
```

Is this possible and how? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should create your myObject without namespaces.

```
XmlDocument myObject = new XmlDocument();
using (XmlTextReader tr = new XmlTextReader(xmlFilepath))
{
    tr.Namespaces = false;
    myObject.Load(tr);
}
```

I have tried the same for creating an object and processing to remove some unwanted nodes, then writing it to another file.

**Sorry I din't read correctly, I thought you were only interested in removing namespaces. This is the update you need to use with previous code**

```
//this assumes your SOAP:Body is a well known tag
//else you may wish to make it a bit generic
XmlNodeList nodeList = myObject.GetElementsByTagName("SOAP:Body");
if (nodeList.Item(0)!= null)
{
    XmlNode item = nodeList.Item(0);
    if (item != null)
    File.WriteAllText("TestOutput.xml", item.InnerXml);
}
```

This gives the output you need.

Comment: It's not working for me, the code doesn't move the declaration